# Wordpress pods io - Rest API for fetching fields information for custom post type

Tags: plugins, rest-api, pods-framework

Hi I have created a custom post type using pods io. Whenever I hit the rest API for a custom post type, I get data for all the posts created using that post type. But what I need from rest API is the configuration of that post type.

That is I need to fetch the label and field type (ex plain text, file/video/image, wysiwyg) for that post type. 
[image]

As shown in the figure above, I need to fetch all the fields information for a particular custom post type.

Is that possible in wordpress using Rest API. Or is there any plugin which does that.

My requirement is that I want to configure fields of different types and I want to fetch fields information for that page. Any plugin which does that would be helpful.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44007869/1374538

Answer (score 3):

On the "REST API" tab, you should be to enable the new post type to show all the custom fields in the standard WordPress REST API.

Also, in each field's options, you should be able to set if that field should be viewable and/or editable via the API, if you only want to show a few fields.

After that, you should be able to see the endpoints for your custom post type in `http://example.com/your_wordpress_site/wp-json/wp/v2`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look what's included in the schema for the endpoint, if that's not enough you need to create your own endpoint and fetch that data from pods! Feel free to contribute your code to pods https://github.com/pods-framework/pods